# How to change the color of the button when pressed? Help

Tags: javascript, custom-button

How to do it through javascript?

Comment: I'm a newbie. Help.

Comment: can you add more details to your question ? is it a button on a Visual force page or a standard button / custom button on a standard page layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information it is a good idea to include more detail when asking a question, e.g. you could include some of your source code, any solutions that you have already tried.

I am going to make an assumption that you have an `<apex:commandButton>`, and that you wish to add a javascript click event handler to the button that can change the color of the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function changeColor(elementId, newColor) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        element.style.background = newColor;
     }
</script>

. . . 

<apex:commandButton id="btn1" 
                    value="Button 1" 
                    onclick="changeColor('{!$Component.btn1}', 'red'); changeColor('{!$Component.btn2}', 'white');" 
                    rerender="container"/>

<apex:commandButton id="btn2" 
                    value="Button 2" 
                    onclick="changeColor('{!$Component.btn1}', 'white'); changeColor('{!$Component.btn2}', 'red');" 
                    rerender="container"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="container">
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: That's almost what I need, but when you click page is loaded and returns the old color. How to get rid of it?

Comment: If you need the button to also call an action on your controller, then using a rerender attribute should do the trick as long as the component that you rerender doesn't contain the button itself.

If you don't need to call an action on the controller you can just use a standard HTML button.

I will updated the code above to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you.
Another question: how to when clicked on the button, and another button to change color?
example: 
if (click button1)  { button1.color="red";  button1.color="blue";}

Comment: Sorry but you will need to reword your sentence/question as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know English badly. For example:  there are two buttons.  
if( Click  button_1) 
{
button_1.background='red';
button_2.background='white';
}
else if( Click  button_2) 
{
button_1.background='white';
button_2.background='red';
}                                                                                                                                                                            How to make such?

Comment: Have updated my answer.

Comment: button_3=Hide();

if( Click button_1) { button_1.background='red'; button_2.background='white'; button_3.background='white'; } else if( Click button_2) { button_1.background='white'; button_2.background='red'; button_3.background='white';  }  
 How to make such?  your answer is not working for this sign, page hangs.  this is due to the fact that the button3 is hidden?

Comment: The purpose of Stack Exchange is to get answers for specific, reasonably-scoped questions. See this page here for more detail: 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Would recommend reading the following Salesforce documentation, and then if need further help with anything specific then submit separate questions:
http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_javascript_intro.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_javascript_intro.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Answer (score 0):

How to make: If click "Manager" then  Manager.backcolor='red' and Employee.backcolor='white'.  Else If click "Employee" then  Manager.backcolor='white' and Employee.backcolor='red' ?                                                                                              Code:

```
      <script>
    function styleButton_Manager(btnEl)
    {    
       var newHexColorStr = 'red';       
       btnEl.style.background = newHexColorStr;   
    }
    function styleButton_Employee(btnEl)
    {    
       var newHexColorStr = '#0000FF'; // blue
       btnEl.style.background = newHexColorStr;
    }
    </script>
    ......................................
 <apex:commandButton rendered="{!manager_mode}" onclick="styleButton_Manager(this)" action="{!toManager}" value="Manager" reRender="container"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:commandButton rendered="{!employee_mode}" onclick="styleButton_Employee(this)" action="{!toEmployee}"  value="Employee" reRender="container"/>
..................................
 <apex:outputPanel id="container">
 ................................
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: See my updated answer.